# C# concat two Collection<string> using linq and getting a Collection<string> result

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to do this:

```
var collection1 = new Collection<string> {"one", "two"};
var collection2 = new Collection<string> {"three", "four"};

var result = collection1.Concat(collection2);
```

But the result variable is type Enumerable[System.String]
, whereas I want a Collection[System.String]

I've tried casting:

```
var all = (Collection<string>) collection1.Concat(collection2);
```

But no joy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var result = new Collection<string>(collection1.Concat(collection2).ToList());
```

For some reason System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection requires an IList parameter to it's constructor.  (The other collections only need an `IEnumerator`)

Answer (score 5):

Use `Enumerable.ToList()`, as `List<>` is an `ICollection<>`.

E.g.:

```
IList list = a.Concat(b).ToList()
```

If you meant `System.ObjectModel.Collection<>` then you will have to pass the created list into the constructor of `Collection<>`, not ideal I know.

```
var collection = new System.ObjectModel.Collection<string>(a.Concat(b).ToList());
```